# How to display html content of an EmailMultiAlternatives mail object

Tags: django, django-email

When sending EmailMultiAlternaitves:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

subject, from_email, to = 'hello', 'from@example.com', 'to@example.com'
text_content = 'This is an important message.'
html_content = '<p>This is an <strong>important</strong> message.</p>'
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.send()
```

How do I display the `"text/html"` alternative when calling the object? E.g.

```
msg.html_content
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the content you're looking for in your `msg.alternatives` which is a list of tuples.

See usage below

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

subject, from_email, to = 'hello', 'from@example.com', 'to@example.com'
text_content = 'This is an important message.'
html_content = '<p>This is an <strong>important</strong> message.</p>'

msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")

# This prints [('<p>This is an <strong>important</strong> message.</p>', 'text/html')]
print(msg.alternatives)

# Prints ('<p>This is an <strong>important</strong> message.</p>', 'text/html')
print(msg.alternatives[0])

# Prints '<p>This is an <strong>important</strong> message.</p>'
print(msg.alternatives[0][0])

msg.send()
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I call that? E.g. what's the syntax to get the html body?

Comment: @alias51 see my updated answer. msg.alternatives points to a list of tuples so there's no method to be called.